# Comparing between two items based on multi factors using an equation

Tags: model, compare, equation

Currently, I want to construct an equation to compare two fruits.

Let say I have a a fruit which has characteristics like weight, length, height, and water content.

I want to build an equation like:
Score = w * weight + l * length + h * height + wc * water content. Each time when a customer comes, there is a new requirement correspinding to the emphasis of a characteristic. This will make the coefficient w, l, h, and wc.

My question is:

- Is there any mathematical method or systematic way to calculate the coefficient based their importance per customer?
- If fruit 1 is 10 kg and fruit 2 is 15kg. Is there any way I can give score to those fruits in terms of their weights?

Kind regards,
Huy Nguyen.